# RxJs pipe map and if condition make one request again

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I want to implement a boolean returning method in angular. I wrote it like this

```
isViewEnabled(id: string): Observable<boolean> {
    const isAppEnabledObs = this.serviceAccessor.isAppEnabled(id, appName);
    const configObs = this.getConfigFromServer(id);
    const isItSharedObs = this.selectionService.getSharingStatus(id);
    return forkJoin([isAppEnabledObs, configObs, isItSharedObs]).pipe(
        map(results => {
        const isAppEnabled = results[0];
        const config = results[1];
        const isItShared = results[2];
        const isToggleEnabled= config ? config.isToggleEnabled: false;
        return !isItShared ? isToggleEnabled : isToggleEnabled && isAppEnabled;
  })
);
```

}

Now I can call all my requests in `forkJoin` and all of them resolves at once. Generally in our app most of the time `isItShared` variable is `false`. Here in this logic `isAppEnabled` variable can only change the condition if and only if `isItShared` variable is `true`.

My question is how to implement this method so that `this.serviceAccessor.isAppEnabled(id, appName);` request is only made if the `isItShared` variable evaluates to `true`. Because most of the time I dont want to call `this.serviceAccessor.isAppEnabled(id, appName);` method as it will slow down the app for most of the cases. I want to go the extra mile if `isItShared` is `true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## An Idiomatic Solution

Call the services that you require first, perform some transformation(s), then use the output of that to call more services. This is often split across multiple observables, but it can easily be done as a unit.

**In essence**: only call `this.selectionService.getSharingStatus` after you've discovered that `isItShared` is true.

You'll see that there are now 3 operations (`forkJoin` -> `map` -> `switchMap`) at work, instead of two. Of course, `map` and `switchMap` can always be combined but I would suggest against it.

Separating out data transformation from subscription logic makes your code much cleaner (and easier to refactor) as your codebase grows.

```ts
isViewEnabled(id: string): Observable<boolean> {

  return forkJoin({
    config: this.getConfigFromServer(id),
    isItShared: this.selectionService.getSharingStatus(id)
  }).pipe(

    map(({config, ...rest}) => ({
      isToggleEnabled: config?.isToggleEnabled || false, 
      ...rest
    })),

    switchMap(({isToggleEnabled, isItShared}) => 
      !isItShared ?
      of(isToggleEnabled) :
      this.selectionService.getSharingStatus(id).pipe(
        map(isAppEnabled => isToggleEnabled && isAppEnabled)
      )
    )

  );

}
```

Comment: Quick question.. as the `switchMap` is explicitly using `isItShared` as as a destructured property, is there any need for the `...rest` spread operator - as opposed to just using `isItShared`

Comment: @Drenai. The spread operator means that's there's less surface-area for bugs. Lets say in the future, you want to add in a third, fourth, or fifth observable into the forkJoin, but still only `config` is mapped to `isToggleEnabled`. Now you only have to change the forkJoin and the switchMap.

The spread operator is more general. It's also more descriptive, that `map` doesn't care how many fields the mapped JS Object has, it just dutifully passes the rest along.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to perform all other checks in your `forkJoin` just the way you're doing now, but move the expensive operation into an `iif` ([docs](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/iif)) branch. Then check your `!isItShared` condition and only switch to `isAppEnabled` if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can leave `isAppEnabledObs` out of your `forkJoin` and use [`switchMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap) to return an observable that only makes the `isAppEnabledObs` call if necessary.

```js
isViewEnabled(id: string): Observable<boolean> {
    const isAppEnabledObs = this.serviceAccessor.isAppEnabled(id, appName);
    const configObs = this.getConfigFromServer(id);
    const isItSharedObs = this.selectionService.getSharingStatus(id);
    
    return forkJoin([configObs, isItSharedObs]).pipe(
        switchMap(([config, isItShared])=> {
            const isToggleEnabled = config ? config.isToggleEnabled: false;

            return !isItShared 
                ? of(isToggleEnabled)
                : isAppEnabledObs.pipe(
                      map(isAppEnabled => isToggleEnabled && isAppEnabled)
                  );
        })
    );
}
```

Inside `switchMap`, we need to return an observable, so we use [`of`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/of) to create observable from `isToggleEnabled` in the case where don't need to make the additional call.

When the call is needed, we simply return an observable that maps the `isAppEnabledObs` response to the desired boolean.